# NSImageView is not deallocated using ARC

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsimageview

Im pretty new to Cocoa development, and I probably do not clearly understand how ARC works.

My problem is that when I'm using NSImageView it is not getting deallocated as I want so the program is leaking memory.

```
__block CMTime lastTime = CMTimeMake(-1, 1);
__block int count = 0;
[_imageGenerator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:stops
                                      completionHandler:^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef image, CMTime actualTime,
                                                                AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error)
     {
         if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded)
         {
             if (CMTimeCompare(actualTime, lastTime) != 0)
             {
                 NSLog(@"new frame found");
                 lastTime = actualTime;
             }
             else
             {
                 NSLog(@"skipping");
                 return;
             }

             // place the image onto the view
             NSRect rect = CGRectMake((count+0.5) * 110, 100, 100, 100);

             // the problem is here!!! ImageView object gets allocated, but never released by the program even though I'm using ARC 

             NSImageView *imgV = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];

             [imgV setImageScaling:NSScaleToFit];
             NSImage *myImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image size:(NSSize){50.0,50.0}];
             [imgV setImage:myImage];
             [self.window.contentView addSubview: imgV];
         }

         if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorFailed)
         {
             NSLog(@"Failed with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
         }
         if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorCancelled)
         {
             NSLog(@"Canceled");
         }
         count++;
     }];
```

Therefore, when I'm returning to this block again t generate new images and display them, everything works perfect except that my program memory use increases by the number of views got created.

If anyone can help me with this I would really appreciate it! Thank you!

Comment: Are you ever removing them from the window's content view?

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work outside of the block. If I do it inside of the block the view gets nothing to display, and the memory still leaks :(

Comment: I can't call release since I'm using ARC, can I?!

Comment: are u sure you have a memory leaks - did you run instruments?

Comment: I didn't run special instruments, but in my activity monitor I cans see that my app is using 8.8MB more memory every time I'm hitting generate button that calls this block and allocates new ImageViews

Comment: why not removing all subviews if there is any when you hit this generate button?

Comment: did u try my method within ur block?

Comment: not yet :) doing it now...actually self.view subviews doesn't work here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't remove your `subviews` when you are generating new ones - make sure you remove your `subviews` before with something along those lines:

```
NSArray *viewsToRemove = [self.contentView subviews];
for (NSView *v in viewsToRemove) {
    [v removeFromSuperview];
}
```

So your problem is not related to the usage of `ARC` actually. Each time you create a `NSImageView` and add it to contentView it is your responsability to remove them before adding a series of new ones. Note that adding those views to `contentView` will increment the `ref count` by one and removing them from the contentView will decrement the ref count by one leading to the memory usage for those views being freed by the system (because nothing else is retaining your views in btw).

Comment: what i tried was to add an array of views used for clean up
    NSMutableArray *viewsToRemove; and adding all those view objects I'm allocation to it...after that do [_viewsToRemove makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)]; it still didn't work :(

Comment: why can't you do the code i mentioned before calling the generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes method? I am sorry i mislead u there is no reason to do it within the block

Comment: to ur first comment you need to remove the views from self.contentView not with the array you are mentioning

Comment: and the most interesting part is...that right now it's not leaking...but also is not showing anything :)))

Comment: outside the block it's not doing anything :(

Comment: try debugging see if all subviews are correctly added and removed

Answer (score 1):

Offending piece of code:

```
[self.window.contentView addSubview: imgV];
```

You've allocated an NSImageView. and keep adding it to the view. You never remove it, meaning the view is creating many references to different instances of the same object, all allocating their own piece of memory.

**Solution:** You'll need to keep track of the view, to make sure you can remove it later. Typically, I use class extensions.

For example:

```
@interface ClassName() {
    NSImageView* m_imgV;
}
@end

....

// place the image onto the view
NSRect rect = CGRectMake((count+0.5) * 110, 100, 100, 100);

if (m_imgV) {
    [m_imgV removeFromSuperView];
}
m_imgV = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];

[m_imgV setImageScaling:NSScaleToFit];
NSImage *myImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image size:(NSSize){50.0,50.0}];
[m_imgV setImage:myImage];
[self.window.contentView addSubview:m_imgV];
```

Comment: I tried to do this but it doesn't really work, since the program keeps  removing m_imgV inside the block, so only the last view is left :(

Comment: I forgot it was in a block, use: `__block NSImageView* m_imgV;` to allow it to be mutable within the block. **Edit:** That might be not what you meant; if you mean your logic might make this method infeasible, then you need to change your logic to take into account memory management.

Comment: Or actually, use `m_imgV.tag = ...` to differentiate between the different `NSImageView`s, whilst still being able to access them individually for removal.

Comment: yeah...it definitely needs more thinking than I initially planned :)) thank you anyways!

Comment: The `.tag` property on `NSViews` allows you to assign a numeric identifier, so that you can track and manage it within a view hierarchy (see tag: in https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html). This means that you can find the view you need to remove, out of numerous other NSImageViews

Comment: so if I have 40 views there, I'll need to assign 40 tags?

Comment: Yes, so you'd keep a tally of tags you've handed out, to make sure each is unique. Then keep a track of which tag refers to which instance, and remove the one you have to, using the tag alone.

Answer (score 0):

I was fighting with this problem for the whole day and finally found the way. For some reason the program wanted me to add a whole function which looks like:

```
// remove all the view from the superview
// and clean up a garbage array
-(void) killAllViews
{
   for (NSImageView *iv in _viewsToRemove)
   {
      [iv removeFromSuperview];
   }
   [_viewsToRemove removeAllObjects]; // clean out the array
}
```

where _viewsToRemove is an array of NSImageViews which I'm filling every time my block is generating new images and adds them to the view.

Still don't understand why just adding the pure code from inside my killAllViews method somewhere into program couldn't solve the problem. Right now I'm basically doing the same, but just calling this method.